# Extracting a HTML tag from a string

Tags: python

Can anyone please explain how would I extract a substring from an input string.

Input:

```
'<h3>freedom machines.</h3><p>dom.</p><br/><p>The robust display.</p>'
```

Output :

```
'<h3>freedom machines.</h3>'
```

I am trying to do it with regex, but no luck.
Do you have any suggestions?

I need to check whether my string starts from **any header tag** (`<h1>`, `<h2>` or `<h3>`), and if it does, I will extract that header tag.

I tried with `startswith`, but with no success:

```
if input.startswith("<h"):
  ** Code to extract that h tag.
```

Comment: whats the pattern your trying to extract ? Please be more specific

Comment: use [beautiful soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) or [elementtree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) to parse (x)html. [never regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4954037).

Comment: I am already using the BeautifulSoup, but, my requirement is little bit different. That's why I had to convert the soup output to a str type.

Answer (score 2):

You can use re.search to extract the text between the `<h3>` tag.

The `<h3>.*?</h3>` pattern means match anything between the `<h3>` tag.

```
>>> import re
>>> text = '<h3>freedom machines.</h3><p>dom.</p><br/><p>The robust display.</p>'
>>> match = re.search("<h3>.*?</h3>", text, re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
>>> print(match.group())

'<h3>freedom machines.</h3>'
```

Comment: The OP needs to check whether his string starts from *any* header tag

Comment: Hey Thanks @Aaron. Suppose, If dont know what type of header tag is used. It can be h1,h2 or h3. So, what could be done in that case ?

Comment: @user3476378 Then try use `<h\d>.*?</h\d>`, the `\d` means a digit.

Comment: @Aaron . Thanks. It did solved my issue. Thanks again.

Comment: That is unfortunately not scalable to a whole html document, but this is rather neat. I'm always impressed by regular expressions...

Answer (score 1):

With BeautifulSoup:

```
html = '<h3>freedom machines.</h3><p>dom.</p><br/><p>The robust display.</p>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
text = soup.find("h3").string
```

This is a basic use of BeautifulSoup.
Create a `BeautifulSoup` object with your string as parameter.
Then use its `find` method to find the tag with the name you're looking for.
Finally, get the text the tag surrounds with its `string` attribute.

If you know that your text is in a `<h1>`, `<h2>` or `<h3>` but you don't know which, just try all of them.
You can even check the three at once:

```
tag = soup.find("h1") or soup.find("h2") or soup.find("h3")
text = tag.string
```

The `or` operator will return the first member that evaluates as `True` Boolean-wise.
In this case, it means the first `soup.find` result that is not `None`.
The `find` method accepts an iterator as well, so you can pass it a static tuple.
The result will be a tag object (if any) that matches any of the asked types.

```
tag = soup.find(("h1", "h2", "h3"))
```

Of course, it is better to know exactly in advance what tag will contain what you want...
If there are both `<h1>` and `<h2>` tags on the page, you won't know what to do...

Comment: Already did this. But, I need to extract only the header tag. I may not know which tag can be there. It can be h3, h2 or h1 .

Comment: @user3476378 That detail needs to be in your question. Anyway, editing my answer.

Comment: Did that. Thanks for letting me know.!

Comment: You can use a list in `find`, eg : `tag = soup.find(["h1", "h2", "h3")`

Comment: @t.m.adam If you really want to do so, use a tuple instead. You don't need a list because it's static, and a tuple is smaller in memory. It's almost nothing, but better style-wise.

Comment: Yes, you can use any iterable, it's up to you.